# 1password secret management and powershell

Tags: powershell, secret-manager, 1password

I am trying to use Microsoft Secret Manager and the secretmanagement.1password extension, I get it all to install and imported, I can create my secretstore for 1password according to the github documentation but I cant Get-SecretInfo from the vault. I get an ERROR, unknown command "list" for "op".

If I use the 1password power cli I can view the vault. Not sure what I am doing wrong, I havent been able to find much documentation on the extension.

Thanks.
https://github.com/cdhunt/SecretManagement.1Password

Comment: Most likely the extension was written for v1.x of the 1Password CLI tool "op". It changed *a lot* between v1 and v2. There is no `op list` sub-command for this tool (any more, I would guess). I had written a whole host of scripts using this command only for them to break completely after a `choco upgrade all`

Comment: It may, however, be possible for you to rewrite the extension. All the operations are still there, but for instance, that extension would like to execute [`op list vault`](https://github.com/cdhunt/SecretManagement.1Password/blob/main/SecretManagement.1Password.Extension/SecretManagement.1Password.Extension.psm1#L25), whereas the new command is `op vault list`. It would be a bit of work, however, as the output has changed as well.

Comment: Thanks @LasseV.Karlsen, I think your probably spot on there. That makes a lot of sense.